# Magento2 Remove JS from Homepage

Tags: magento2, javascript, home-page

In my website homepage there are multiple bundle js

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://website.com/static/version1545621016/frontend/website/default/fr_FR/js/bundle/bundle0.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://website.com/static/version1545621016/frontend/website/default/fr_FR/js/bundle/bundle1.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://website.com/static/version1545621016/frontend/website/default/fr_FR/js/bundle/bundle2.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://website.com/static/version1545621016/frontend/website/default/fr_FR/js/bundle/bundle3.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://website.com/static/version1545621016/frontend/website/default/fr_FR/js/bundle/bundle4.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://website.com/static/version1545621016/frontend/website/default/fr_FR/js/bundle/bundle5.min.js"></script>
```

why all are there?I want to remove it for homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off JS bundling in the admin `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer` (Developer mode) or via CLI if you're in Production mode:

> php -f bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 1

With JS bundling enabled Magento takes a big performance hit. Inchoo did a post that illustrated this well - https://inchoo.net/magento-2/javascript-bundling-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

make a change xml file in a your theme

> app/design/frontend/website/default/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

Content file **cms_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <head>
    <remove src="js/bundle/bundle0.js"/>
 </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi @mrtuvn how do we remove 3rd party js from home page but that 3rd party js should on remaining pages