# magento 2 remove root lib/web/ js files from home page

Tags: magento2.3, requirejs, optimization, pagespeed, remove

Magento 2 sends around 300 request on home page so speed is very slow.
Also, bundling create very large file so its taken time to load resources. 
I want to remove js from root lib/web from home page.

Is there any way to remove all unnecessary js?

Regards
Hiren Shah

Comment: so do you want to exclude js files from bundling?

Answer (score -1):

If you know which js files are not required the you can just [follow this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255708/magento2-remove-js-from-homepage)

Please let me know if it solve your problem. Thanks